# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Cart`. Teact.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making E-commerce website just I want to add to cart .  when I click add to cart button then add Product on my cart but its showing error , and I use a lot of method but I did not solve. can you explain cleanly

getting this error I tried to fixed but I could not , where  I am making mistake

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Cart`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at div
    at Cart (http://localhost:3000/main.f51a13b4a1752c213b98.hot-update.js:34:71)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49574:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49997:5)
    at div
    at App
    at CartContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:713:5)
    at ProductContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:806:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49935:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48282:5)
```

Home page

```
import React from 'react';
import { CartState } from "../Context/ProductContext";
import Navbar from "../Components/Navbar/Navbar";
import SingleProduct from "../Components/Products/SingleProduct";
import "../Components/Products/SingleProduct.css";
import { CartStatus } from "../Context/CartContext";

const Home = () => {
  //custom hook useContext
  const { Product} = CartState();
  console.log("Product:", Product);
   
  return (
     <>
      <Navbar/>

      <div className="Product_wrapper"> 
      {Product?.map((products, i) => (
            <SingleProduct key={products.id} products={products}/>   
      )    
         )}
   
      </div>
     </>
  )
}
```

Single Product

```
import React from 'react';
import "../Products/SingleProduct.css";
import { CartStatus } from "../../Context/CartContext";


//Add to product using Dispatch

const SingleProduct = ({ products }) => {
     const {Cart , dispatch} =  CartStatus() 
      //  console.log("DEMON:", Cart);  

      const addToCart = (products)=>{
         dispatch({ type:"ADD_CART", playload:products})
      }
  return (
    <div className="product_container">
         <img src={products.image}    className="img" alt={products.name} />
          <h1>{products.title}</h1>
          <span>₹{products.price}</span> 
           <button 
             onClick={(products) =>{
              addToCart(products)
             }}
           className="btn">Add</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SingleProduct;
```

Cart

```
import React from 'react';
import AddToCart from "../Components/Cart/AddToCart";
import { CartStatus } from "../Context/CartContext";
import "../Components/Products/SingleProduct.css";
// import { CartState } from "../Context/ProductContext";


const Cart = () => {
const {Cart, dispatch} = CartStatus();
        console.log("LLL:" ,Cart);

  return (
    <div className="Product_wrapper">
       {Cart.map((products,i) =>(
          <div className="product_container" key={products.id}>
            <img src={products.image}  className="img" alt={products.name} />
             <h1>{products.title}</h1>
          </div>

       ))}
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default Cart;
```

I'm using UseContext and UseReducer for make

Comment: looks like you have two products with the same id

Comment: Does it work correct if you add the same product twice? In that case their product.id would be the same.